# NoMethodError in Controller#show - Nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

It might look like a newbie question but I can't get my head around it. Rails is telling me that the method is not defined even if I can access it in the console. I'm missing something obviously...

Here is my routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root   'static_pages#home'
    resources :users do
    resources :bodies
  end
end
```

Here is the User model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bodies, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Here is the Body model

```
class Body < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Here is the Bodies Controller

```
class BodiesController < ApplicationController

  def new
      @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
      @body = @user.bodies.new
  end

  def create
    @body = current_user.bodies.build(body_params)
      if @body.save
        redirect_to user_body_path(@body)
      else
        render 'new'
      end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @body = @user.bodies(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @bodies = Body.all
  end
private

  def body_params
    params.require(:body).permit(:weight, :sex, :age, :fat)
  end

end
```

The create action is working fine. I'm just struggling to get the Show action to work although the right parameters are passed along :

```
Showing /Users/rodolphegeant/code/FFL/app/views/bodies/show.html.erb where line #9 raised:

undefined method `sex' for #<Body::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f820f65da90>
Did you mean?  send
Extracted source (around line #9):
7
8
9
10
11
12

Hello from my Body

<%= @body.sex %> | <%= @body.age %> | <%= @body.weight %> | <%= @body.fat %>




Rails.root: /Users/rodolphegeant/code/FFL

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/bodies/show.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_bodies_show_html_erb___2597620731841156962_70098290142700'
Request

Parameters:

{"user_id"=>"1", "id"=>"3"}
```

When I go to the console I can run @body.sex or @body.age or any other method that corresponds to the attributes I'm looking for....

Thanks a lot in advance for helping me resolve this issue.

Codingly yours,

Rodolphe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run find query on records which will return from the association with user model.

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @body = @user.bodies.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: Yes perfect! Thank you Ahmed :)

Answer (score 0):

HI in show action in your controller replace `@user.bodies(params[:id])` by `Body.find(params[:id])`

Comment: This is working fine. Sadly I can only vote for one solution. The other solution below works also, It just makes more sense semantically for me. I'd like, however, to thank you for your help.